# Namespace and class conflict

Tags: c#

This is a bad title for the question, but I can't think of a better one.

I have a namespace called `Globals` with a class `X` in it. I also have a class called `Globals`. When I try to access `Globals.X.StaticMember` it tries to access the class `Globals.X` and complains that `X` doesn't exist. How do I reference the namespace `Globals`, i.e. `::Globals.X.StaticMember`? (`::` doesn't compile.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `global::Globals.X.StaticMember`.

And Globals are Evil!

Comment: Except for singletons and static classes, both of which are essentially globals.

Answer (score 8):

Eric Lippert recently blogged about it.  Four blog posts no less, [check it out](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/default.aspx).  Start at part one.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert recently had a series of blogposts describing the problems you run into when using the same name for a class and a namespace, explaining this statement from the Framework Design Guidelines in section 3.4:

> “do not use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace”.

See here for the various posts:

> **[Do not name a class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)** ([Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/15/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three.aspx), [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/18/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four.aspx))