# Namespace access issue with sub namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have two classes in the different sub namespaces:

```
namespace Acme.ByteTools
{
        class ByteTools
        {
        ...
        }
}

namespace Acme.IO
{
        class Reader
        {
        ...
        }
}
```

While I trying to access Acme.ByteTools from the any third namespace, I use:

```
using Acme.ByteTools;
...
ByteTools.BytesToUint(...);
```

but when I try to access Acme.ByteTools from Acme.IO, compiler require different notation:

```
using Acme.ByteTools;
...
ByteTools.ByteTools.BytesToUint(...);
```

Why?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to give classes the same names as their containing namespace.

Comment: Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2787425/394487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others including the legendary Eric Lippert have stated...please don't create collisions.  I've seen code riddled with using alias directives because of collisions and I simply cannot express how frustrating it is to see a namespace change its name from class to class.

The confusion speaks for itself.  Just look at something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();//A's a namespace
            A.A b = new A.A();//A is a namespace this works!
            global::A.A nuts = new A();//This fails...ugh
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace A
{    
    class A
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            A a = new A();//A's a class
            A.A b = new A.A();//A is a type (class) A.A makes no sense to the compiler
            global::A.A nuts = new A();//Oh but this works fine
        }

    }
}
```

So the fix is make sure the namespaces and classes are different.  A using alias directive `using B = A;` might ease the pain however that directive can change from file to file and anything to its right must be fully qualified.